# How to append more than 2 FILE PATH (as same as append() )

Tags: r, append

The current method its too redundant to glue every list one by one .

```
# CURRENT METHOD
FL_PATH_1 <- list.files(path = "~/MY_FOLDER_1"),
                              pattern = "*.CSV",full.name = T)
FL_PATH_2 <- list.files(path = "~/MY_FOLDER_2"),
                              pattern = "*.CSV",full.name = T)
FL_PATH_3 <- list.files(path = "~/MY_FOLDER_3"),
                              pattern = "*.CSV",full.name = T)

FL_PATH_BP_A <- append(FL_PATH_1 ,FL_PATH_2)
FL_PATH_BP_A_2 <- append(FL_PATH_BP_A,FL_PATH_3)

DT <- rbindlist(lapply(FL_PATH_BP_A_2 ,import,header=T,sep=",",
                          setclass = "data.table"))
```

Are there any effective and flexible method to solve this case ?
*every list they have to be list.files() as they are taking all files in certain folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
folders <- c("folder1","folder2","folder3")
files <- c()
for (folder in folders) {
  files <- c(list.files(folder, pattern = "*.CSV",full.name = T)))
}
```